# How can I have multiple document.observe(dom:loaded ...) functions inside one javascript file? (prototype)

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype

Basically what I'm after is, following squashing all my JavaScript into one file (or a few files) how can I make a document.observe(dom:loaded({...})) function call for the right page?

So, say I have 5 pages in my website, and each one has a separate JS file. Inside each file is a load of page related functions, and a special function which sets up eventhandlers etc when the DOM has loaded. Obviously if all 5 pages include their own JS files then that's fine. But I want to compact all my JS into one page for versioning and efficiency reasons.

Therefore, in doing this, I would end up with 5 "dom:loaded" functions waiting to be setup. This won't do as the stuff inside these functions is page specific. So, my question is how can I do what I want to do without causing a whole bunch of DOM errors, and false eventhandler setup requests?

Ive considered namespaces and stuff like that but don't really know anything about it/them.

Btw, I'm using the Prototype lib. Oh, and my sites are considerably larger than 5 pages! :)

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:
inspect the dom to identify the page. For example, attach an attribute to the body element.
put a script tag in the page that sets a variable.
inspect the url.

when the load event fires, the event handler identifies the page and hands control off to the proper code.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I had kinda considered those ideas but had brushed them off as a bit "hacky". I guess Im just being too fussy. Ill give them a go. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would give different IDs to the `<body>`s of the separate HTML files and test in the dom:loaded event the name of the `<body>` element using `$$('body')[0].id`.

Comment: Thanks very much. Im going to give this a go along with Chris' suggestions above.

Answer (score 0):

I have opted to use a php regexp to capture the URI, then use this as the body ID. On my sites, where the page names are static, it means each page will have a unique ID.

I then include a JS file in the HEAD which contains a switch block inside which the appropriate code/functions are loaded. The switch block is inside the document.observe(dom:loaded...) function.

Works a treat!

Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to always write my .js with no self activation (so much as possible)...

psuedo-code

```
namespace('mysite.section.init');
mysite.section.init.pageName = function(){
  //stuff to run here...
};
```

in your home page, at the bottom, or via dom:loaded event simply run `mysite.section.init.pageName();`